# Не включается код Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
import time
from config import *
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Вы забыли дописать аргумент')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("Не хватает прав:angry:")
class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Button",style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def gray_button(self,button:discord.ui.Button,interaction:discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"This is an edited button response!")
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member, ctx):
    embedr = discord.Embed(title="Привет")
    embedr.add_field(name="Начало", value="Прочитай правила, ой забыл привет. Дальше разговаривай получай роль и т.д")
    await bot.fetch_user(user_id=member.id).send(embed=embedr)
@bot.command()
async def send_invite(ctx,max_age=1,max_uses=1):
    days = max_age * 60 * 24
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=days,max_uses=max_uses)
    await ctx.send(invite)
    print(f"invite link = {invite}")
@bot.command()

async def invites(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    day = 10 * 60 * 24
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=day,max_uses=10)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Привет", color=0x85CF44)
    embedVar.set_author(
        name=f"{ctx.message.author}",
        icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/app-icons/993760621596246090/99190b88938aba56c1b09b4aaccea39f.png?size=256",
    )
    embedVar.add_field(name="Начало", value=f"***Привет я тебя отправляю приглащение на сервер {ctx.guild.name} для приглашение друзей ***", inline=True)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Ссылка", value=f"***ссылка {invite} у тебя есть время 10 дней и пригласить вы можете 10 человек***", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Кто выдал", value=f"***Вам выдал эту ссылку человек {ctx.message.author.mention}***")
    await user.send(embed=embedVar)
    await user.send(f"{user.mention}")
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    ctx.send("test.start")
    time.sleep("test 100%")
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):

    embedVar = discord.Embed(title='Был забанен', color=0xc000000)
    embedVar.set_author(
        name=f"{ctx.message.author}",
        icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/app-icons/993760621596246090/99190b88938aba56c1b09b4aaccea39f.png?size=256"
    )
    embedVar.add_field(name="За что?", value=f"***Вы были забанен(а) за {reason} на сервере {ctx.guild.name}***")
    embedVar.add_field(name="Кто выдал?", value=f"***Вы были забанены {ctx.message.author}***")
    await member.send(embed=embedVar)
    await member.send("До новых встеч")
    await ctx.send(f"Был забанен {member.mention}")
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Messenge test", view=Buttons())

bot.run(settingsAres["token"])
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Msi_Pc\Desktop\ \1\main.py", line 65, in <module>
        async def test(ctx):
      File "C:\Users\Msi_Pc\Desktop\ \1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1513, in decorator
        self.add_command(result)
      File "C:\Users\Msi_Pc\Desktop\ \1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 245, in add_command
        super().add_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\Msi_Pc\Desktop\ \1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1348, in add_command
        raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command test is already an existing command or alias.
```

Comment: Ошибка гласит что команда `test` уже существует либо как команда, либо как алиас команды. В коде у вас 2 функции с одинаковым названием `test`

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке говорится, что команда test уже есть.

В вашем коде две команды test. Переименуйте одну из них.

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    ctx.send("test.start")
    time.sleep("test 100%")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Messenge test", view=Buttons())
```